# How to explain delete SQL query but not perform it? (I need figure the records to delete out)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to understand how many records will my sql query delete, but perform it later, after I understand the quantity is right. Does `EXPLAIN DELETE FROM` do this? ( I cannot experiment due to data value)

The RDBMS is PostgreSQL but I'm sure this is common for any RDBMS

Comment: You could perform the DELETE in a transaction and roll back the transaction.  If you're *really* worried about data loss then the best approach is to replicate the database and run your tests against the copy.  (For critical production data it's always good to periodically replicate into a testing/staging environment anyway.)

Comment: @David Just a note: refreshing to non-prod is sometimes not advisable, specially if you have PII agreements or restrictions. Maybe a prod-similar env could be of use in these cases (staging, for example) if they are controlled correctly.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Good point, data should certainly be anonymized if being moved out of non-Production control.  For "testing" I don't necessarily mean QA or development, but more like smoke testing against Production volume.  You're right, and I should have been clear on that, any environment with Production data should be controlled under the same security as Production itself.

Comment: Just don't use DELETE, but a SELECT count(*) to see how many records it would affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXPLAIN ANd ANALYSE will show you how many rows are affected, but only when you add an actual filter to the query, like TheImpaler showed in the comment see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=069785461713ea8f7bb9751a70396dbc

> ```
> explain analyze delete from t where a % 2 = 0;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                        |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Delete on t  (cost=0.00..48.25 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.028..0.029 rows=0 loops=1)          |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..48.25 rows=13 width=6) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=3 loops=1) |
> |         Filter: ((a % 2) = 0)                                                                     |
> |         Rows Removed by Filter: 3                                                                 |
> | Planning Time: 0.255 ms                                                                           |
> | Execution Time: 0.121 ms                                                                          |
> ```

But basically every `SELECT (COUNT(*)` with your where clause should do the same

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tab1(id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(1)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(2)
> ```

> ```
> BEGIN;
> DELETE FROM tab1;
> ROLLBACK;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 2 rows affected
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b79074958968cd8ac0712f33376c1c77)*

Comment: Actually ANALYZE does produce the count of deleted rows, but under a different property (`Rows Removed by Filter`). See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=069785461713ea8f7bb9751a70396dbc

Comment: does `explain analyze delete from t where a % 2 = 0;
` delete records or explain only?

Comment: no you need bith explain and analyse and a where clause for that to work

Comment: BTW `BEGIN;
DELETE FROM tab1;
ROLLBACK;` does not expose how many records were deleted and rolled back after

Comment: yes it shows the affected rows. see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ac0eab670815913a3c331e6002cc2736

Comment: aah, sorry I mean in my sql editor... I believe your fiddler shows it, but I cannot move my data to there... anyway `SELECT COUNT(*) ` works